# AS3 mouseClick ignore a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, movieclip

Is there a way in AS3 to make a the mouse ignore a certain movieclip? I need it to be on top of the other movieclips (due to transparancy effects), but have it in a way that allows clicking on the movieclips underneath it. I know about ".mouseChildren = false", but that only makes all the stuff inside that movieclip unclickable, but it still functions as a "barrier" on top of all the others buttons.

Is there a way to do this, or do I need to remove it completely ?

Comment: mv.mouseEnabled = false; mv.mouseChildren = false;

Comment: Thank you, that does it. Please do a Answer and I'll accept it. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set both `.mouseChildren` and `.mouseEnabled` to false before you can click on objects behind the MovieClip. This makes the mouse ignore the objects within the MovieClip and the MovieClip itself.

Source: http://pixelfumes.blogspot.com/2008/01/clicking-through-movieclips-to.html

EDIT: Oops, didn't see that comment by Alex, sorry.